# Logging the user in and out

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 php files
first file name is mysql_login_an.php:

```
<?php
if(!mysql_connect('localhost','root','root') || !mysql_select_db('d_database')){
echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

second file name is mysql_form.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'mysql_login_an.php';
if(isset($_GET['user'])&&isset($_GET['password']))
{
$user=$_GET['user'];
$password=$_GET['password'];
$password_hash=md5($password);
$user_hash=md5($user);

    if(!empty($user) && !empty($password))
    {

        $query="SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$user' and `password`='$password'";
        if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
        {
            $mysql_num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
            if($mysql_num_rows==0)
            {
            echo 'invalid user';
            }
            elseif($mysql_num_rows>=1)
            {

            $user_id=mysql_result($query_run,0,`id`);
            $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;
            Header('Location:login_success.php');

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'error';
    }
}
?>
<form action='#' method='GET'>
user <input type='text' name='user'><br><br>
pass <input type='password' name='password'><br>
<input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
```

and third file name is function.php

```
<?php
require 'mysql_form.php';

function delete_cookie()
{
    if(isset($_GET['action'])&&$_GET['action']=='logout')
    {
    require 'mysql_form.php';
    session_destroy();
    header('location:mysql_form.php');
    }
    else
    {
    $firstname=get_user_info('firstname');
    $surname=get_user_info('surname');
    echo "hello  $firstname $surname ,U are login successfully  <a href='mysql_form.php?action=logout'>log out </a>";
    }
}
delete_cookie();

function get_user_info($field)
{
$query="SELECT $field FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
    {
        if($query_result=mysql_result($query_run,0,$field)){
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I want it output the firstname surname (in my database) and the logout button.But it also display the login form.How to fix this.Here is the picture my screen when i logged in
http://upanh.com/view/?s=upload&id=3rr49kaganc

Comment: Remember to add session_start() to the beginning of each of the files

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I just want it display the firstname, surname and logout button when i log in but not also the login from.Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Make some if - else for displaying form, now it's displayed by default.

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])&&isset($_GET['password']))
{
... 
}
else
{
... display form...
}
```